# PyDictionary can't connect to wordnetweb site

Tags: python, pydictionary

I am trying to execute a basic `PyDictionary` Python code, but I am getting a connection error even though I'm connected to the Internet.

---

Here is my code:

```
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
dictionary=PyDictionary()
print (dictionary.meaning("Diligent"))
```

---

```
Error: The Following Error occured: HTTPConnectionPool(host='wordnetweb.princeton.edu', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /perl/webwn?s=Diligent (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000000000A207CC0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',))None
```

Comment: Sure it's the right URL? (try `http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu` instead of `wordnetweb.princeton.edu`)

Comment: Actually its from PyDictionary package, I think yes. its a right URL.

Comment: Consider posting an issue [here](https://github.com/geekpradd/PyDictionary/issues)

Comment: The error means that it couldn't connect to the URL that's used by `PyDictionary`, which is peculiar. I could just connect to it. This is a shot in the dark, but try reinstalling the module? Did you just install it? Is this your first time using it?

Comment: Just to make sure, do you get the error if you run `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup; import requests; BeautifulSoup(requests.get('http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=Diligent').text, 'html.parser')`

Comment: I am getting this error when i try to execute the above mentioned code

Comment: `gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    140             conn = connection.create_connection(
--> 141                 (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
    142 

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     59 
---> 60     for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
     61         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res`